# How to find out the dependency of a table in SQL

Tags: sql

Is there is any way to find out the dependency of a table. I mean to say which stored procedure is affecting data of the table.

Comment: sql tag is a little bit vague for this kind of request... Which DBMS is concerned ?

Answer (score 0):

try this command :

```
SELECT DISTINCT so.name
 FROM syscomments sc
 INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id=so.id
 WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%tablename%'
 ----Option 2
 SELECT DISTINCT o.name, o.xtype
 FROM syscomments c
 INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id
 WHERE c.TEXT LIKE '%tablename%'
```